# SQLite .NetCompact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am creating a Pocket PC application in C# and I want to add the SQLLite DB and Create Tables. When I compile the project I get the error as

Error   1

> The type
>   'System.Data.Common.DbConnection' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.Data,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. C:\Documents
>   and
>   Settings\build\Desktop\TestPPCApplication\Database.cs 40  17  TestPPCApplication

Any One Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you are missing a reference for the System.Data assembly or you are referencing a non compact framework version of System.Data.Common.DbConnection

Comment: I have a reference to System.Data. But I am not able to see the System.Data.Common.DbConnection in the .Net references

Comment: That particular object is located in the System.Data assembly. Mine is located here C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\

Comment: Make sure you have not reference the full framework version of the SQLlite dlls as well

Comment: I added the reference System.Data from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\   But still I am receiving the error.  Could you please tell me how can I check that I am referencing the full version of sqllite dlls

Comment: I have added the reference for SqlLite Syste.Data.Sqllite